# What are the effects of using two synonyms "видаться" and "увидеться" in a row?

Tags: глаголы

> Р. S. Если Вы **видаетесь и увидитесь** съ Бернгардомъ Васильевичемъ, то потрудитесь передать ему и семейству его мой сердечный поклонъ.

As far as I know, their meanings seem quite similar, if not the same. Why use two consecutive synonyms like this -- and a juxtaposition of an imperfective verb and a perfective verb, at that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Видаетесь** means see one another habitually, on a regular basis, which is suggested by its imperfective aspect. BTW this form is obsolete. Today we'd say **видитесь**.

**Увидитесь** in this context means will see one another soon, in a short while, next time.

I can think of 2 justifications for their combined use:
1) they denote different types of action
2) purely literary aesthetic considerations.

The reason for use of **видаетесь** instead of **видитесь** (provided the latter form was current at the time of the text composition) could be that since the latter is consonant with **увидитесь** thereby creating a semblance of tautology, which is frowned upon in the ethos of Russian composition, it was discarded in favor of an alternative form for the sake of euphony.

Comment: I see. Incidentally, are "съ / поклонъ" outdated versions of "с / поклон" respectively?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens indeed, and nowadays people don't send bows to one another, the entire phrase is built in an old fashion.

Comment: Do you mean both "поклонъ" and "поклон" sound too outdated to say "give one's best regards" in our times?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens pretty much, this is archaic type of manners... the word поклон is the same in both cases, what differs is spelling, which nevertheless doesn't translate into actual speech

Comment: I guess "видаться" is one of those instances where the *obsolete* tag is sorely lacking in its dictionary entry...

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens in modern language the verb is only used with prefix по-, повидаться which makes its aspect perfective, its imperfective form is видиться as i mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

если Вы видаетесь = если Вы достаточно регулярно (встречаетесь, видите друг друга)

если Вы увидитесь = если Вы в будущем еще раз его встретите